# ¿Cómo fuerzo el SSL en backoffice Prestashop?

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, seguridad, ssl

No consigo forzar el `HTTPS://` para el backoffice de [prestashop](/questions/tagged/prestashop)

He probado a activar el `SSL` en el backoffice y a marcar "forzar SSL" pero no funciona ...

Comment: el .htacess no afecta al backoffice, por tanto no habra redirección automatica, si ingresas con http, no te redirigira a https. Por tanto debes ingresar en el back office siempre con https.

Comment: El objetivo es FORZAR para que los comerciales no tengan que estar pendiente de redirecciones a http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya se como hacerlo, hay que añadir esto:

```
{literal}
    <script>
        if (location.protocol != 'https:') {
            location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        }
    </script>
{/literal}
```

En `/miweb.com/admin/themes/default/template/footer.tpl`

Así, al ser por javascript no hay problemas con los módulos (Como redsys) que no gestionan https de forma correcta :)